# Compiling and communication with shell application in Android/Java

Tags: java, android, shell, exec

I have a command line application (also it's source code in C language). I want to use it in my first android application.

Here are my questions:

1. I have a compiled executable for mac. Should I recompile it for android? If yes, how?
2. Is it possible to have a two way communication with an executable in shell in Java/Android?

I'm looking for something like:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

After a lot of googling, that line of code was only thing that I found. But I don't want to close the executable after each call (it communicates with a server on the internet). Here is what I want to do:

```
1. Open shell executable
2. write AAA
3. read line
4. write BBB
5. read line
6. write CCC
...
98. write XYZ
99. read line
100. close executable
```

Note that there may be nothing to read, and it shouldn't wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you need recompile it with NDK. How: you can find more information on official Android site, where [examples](https://developer.android.com/ndk/samples/index.html) also present.
2. Yes its also possible to do that, and there are two ways exist:
   a) JNI. You need to write a wrapper for for you function, and compile a shared library
   b) You can compile executable file, run it and communicate via input/output stream. Something like:

   ```
        try {
           Process pb = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
           String line;
           BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pb.getInputStream()));
           while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
               System.out.println("Input from your C/C++ app: " + line);
           }
           input.close();

       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   ```